# Resizing image in Kotlin and flutter loosing quality with NodeJs backend

Tags: node.js, flutter, kotlin, multer, sharp

so here is the issue. I have 2 apps , Kotlin and flutter which uses NodeJs as backend. So I save images to my mongo db using NodeJs , Multer and Sharp. I convert the images to buffer. So when I retrieve the images from my db, the images are blurry. The colours don't stand out.
Here is the configuration for Multer

```
    const uploadMarketPic = multer({
 limits: {
        fieldSize: 1500000
 },
 fileFilter(req, file, cb){
         if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bitmap|bmp)$/)){
                console.log("Image Files are expected!")
                return cb(new Error("Image Files are expected!"))
         }
         cb(undefined, true);
        }
})
```

And here is how I use Sharp Js

```
        const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({width: 1024, height:1024}).jpeg().toBuffer();
```

I retrieve the buffer and process it with this function in flutter

```
 Uint8List _getImageBinary() {
            List<int> intList = (allProductsAsList as List)[index]['productPic']['data'].cast<int>().toList();
            Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(intList);
            setState(() {
              byteImager = data;
            });
            return data;
          }
```

I later use MemoryImage() or Image.memory() for the returned data. I want to be able to resize to any height without losing quality, I honestly don't know where the issue is coming from. Thanks

Comment: *I want to be able to resize to any height without losing quality,* - you will have to use vector graphics for that. Raster file formats will always lose quality when scaled

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thank you, please how do I go about that? Plus are you talking for flutter or Kotlin please. Thanks again, atleast I know where to start my research from